# How to configure markdown with reveal.js?

Tags: markdown, reveal.js

I want to use reveal.js with markdown. I followed the [full set up](https://revealjs.com/installation/)
installation guide

1. install node.js
2. Clone the reveal.js repository
3. Move to the reveal.js folder and install dependencies
4. run `npm start` inside reveal.js folder

and then I have modified the `index.html` page to add markdown following [the documentation](https://revealjs.com/markdown/)

```
<section data-markdown>
<textarea data-template>
## slide 1 
please add me another slide

---
## slide 2
I _need_ it 

---
## slide 3
</textarea>
</section>
```

However the markdown is not fully working :
[image: reveal.js problem with markdown]

Everything is on the same slide and the 2nd line should be a paragrapher.
what should I do ?

reveal.js@4.0.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to specify the data separator, in the example is "---"

```
<section data-markdown data-separator="---">
```

:)

and take into account what the documentation says

> Note that this is sensitive to indentation (avoid mixing tabs and spaces) and line breaks (avoid consecutive breaks).

Comment: `<section data-markdown data-separator="---">` was the solution and unfortunately it is not preent in the doc (version 4.0.0). Thank you.

Comment: This is correct (and really should be in the documentation) but if you do use `---` as your separator, it will take precedence if you try to use markdown tables and not render correctly. You could use `===` as your slide and change the line above to be `<section data-markdown data-separator="===">` which will let you keep using tables.